# Safari not loading pages, other browsers doing fine

Tags: macos, network, safari

I have an issue many seem to have: Safari 7.0.5 (and now 7.0.6) hangs when loading web pages whereas other browsers (Chrome, Firefox) work just fine. I've ran my tests on WiFi with two different routers as well as through iPhone tethering.

Here are the steps I have taken so far but the problem persists:

- re-installed my MacBook Air completely with the latest image from the App Store
- Reset Safari
- Disabled extensions
- Unchecked "Warn when visiting fraudulent website"
- Unchecked "Stop plug-ins to save power"
- In the Develop menu, checked "Disable caches"
- In WiFi settings, disabled IPv6
- Changed DNS to OpenDNS
- Deleted all Safari plist, caches, favicons cache, etc.
- Turned off Safari in iCloud settings
- Fixed permissions, rebooted
- Disabled the prefetch setting from terminal
- Emptied all my logs, launched Safari and tried to open this url: https://pragprog.com/login . Here is the (anonymised) result:

```
20/08/14 17:12:05.179 ubd[178]: ApplePushService: Timed out making blocking call, failed to perform call via XPC connection to 'com.apple.apsd'
20/08/14 17:12:05.681 AOSPushRelay[252]: ApplePushService: Timed out making blocking call, failed to perform call via XPC connection to 'com.apple.apsd'
20/08/14 17:12:05.909 parentalcontrolsd[271]: StartObservingFSEvents [849:] -- *** StartObservingFSEvents started event stream
20/08/14 17:12:06.112 UserEventAgent[11]: Captive: CNPluginHandler en0: Authenticated
20/08/14 17:12:06.513 accountsd[212]: /SourceCache/Accounts/Accounts-336.9/ACDAuthenticationPluginManager.m - -[ACDAuthenticationPluginManager credentialForAccount:client:handler:] - 230 - The authentication plugin for account “myname@gmail.com" (20DDC449-9F11-4479-8D9C-11BBC43D96AD) could not be found!
20/08/14 17:12:06.514 accountsd[212]: /SourceCache/Accounts/Accounts-336.9/ACDAccountStore.m - __62-[ACDAccountStore credentialForAccountWithIdentifier:handler:]_block_invoke389 - 857 - No plugin provides credentials for account myname@gmail.com. Falling back to legacy behavior.
20/08/14 17:12:06.668 com.apple.time[148]: Interval maximum value is 946100000 seconds (specified value: 9223372036854775807).
20/08/14 17:12:06.708 com.apple.NotesMigratorService[272]: Joined Aqua audit session
20/08/14 17:12:06.784 gamed[215]: CKSoftwareMap: Registering with Daemon
20/08/14 17:12:06.922 soagent[188]: No active accounts, killing soagent in 10 seconds
20/08/14 17:12:06.925 soagent[188]: No active accounts, killing soagent in 10 seconds
20/08/14 17:12:08.771 login[276]: USER_PROCESS: 276 ttys000
20/08/14 17:12:14.115 apsd[99]: Failed to evaluate trust: No error. (0), result=5; retrying with revocation checking optional
20/08/14 17:12:16.041 login[276]: DEAD_PROCESS: 276 ttys000
20/08/14 17:12:17.915 soagent[188]: Killing soagent.
20/08/14 17:12:17.916 NotificationCenter[175]: SOHelperCenter main connection interrupted
20/08/14 17:12:17.916 com.apple.dock.extra[183]: SOHelperCenter main connection interrupted
20/08/14 17:12:17.917 NotificationCenter[175]: SOHelperCenter main connection interrupted
20/08/14 17:12:17.919 imagent[194]: [Warning] Denying xpc connection, task does not have entitlement: com.apple.private.icfcallserver  (soagent:188)
20/08/14 17:12:17.919 imagent[194]: [Warning] Denying xpc connection, task does not have entitlement: com.apple.private.icfcallserver  (soagent:188)
20/08/14 17:12:21.911 Dropbox[210]: ICARegisterForEventNotification-Has been deprecated since 10.5.  Calls to this function in the future may crash this application.  Please move to ImageCaptureCore
20/08/14 17:12:23.437 com.apple.SecurityServer[15]: Session 100006 created
20/08/14 17:12:24.189 apsd[99]: Unrecognized leaf certificate
20/08/14 17:12:39.791 apsd[99]: Unrecognized leaf certificate
20/08/14 17:13:48.016 apsd[99]: Failed to send activation record to service com.apple.ManagedClient.enroll
```

I also deleted all the passwords in my keychain, deleted all the bookmarks and emptied the reading list, just in case there was some corruption there. Still no success. I tried to log in with the guest account as well but the problem is the same.

Comment: Did you have parental control enabled - in your settings or router?

Answer (score 1):

By verifying the issue in the Guest user you have identified the issue resides in a system shared resource.
Attempt to reproduce the issue in [Safe Mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1564). If the issue is not reproducible, reboot normally and check if the issues persist. If it does I would encourage you to backup your system and navigate over to the local Library located at */Library*. From here you can start troubleshooting by removing files from locations such as:

- ./StartupItems
- ./LaunchAgents
- ./LaunchDaemons
- ./Internet Plug-ins

Reboot your system and attempt to reproduce after each change. If all else fails you may be looking at an erase and install of your OS and selective migrating your data back on to the drive to avoid migrating the issue over.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The issue persists in safe mode. I already reinstalled the OS, this is a clean install.

Comment: You mentioned in your post "re-installed my MacBook Air completely with the latest image from the App Store". This would imply you installed the OS on top of your existing system which would not be a "clean" install, a clean install would imply you deleted **everything**

Comment: no, of course not. When I mean "clean install", what I did is downloaded Mavericks from the App Store, created a bootable USB drive, booted on it, formatted my HD completely and then installed. So, yeah, fresh install. Reading the log, I'm wondering if my issue could be linked to certificates in my keychain.